# How Epic are the Epic Robe weapons?

Tags: magicka

The gamer DLC pack introduced three new robe, the zombie, the tentacle and the epic. The effect of the first two is easy to understand, but I don't understand what the Epic Sword and Epic Staff does.

The inventory description for the sword say that is has "Epic effects". Right, when I hit with it, there are some white sparks shooting out of the sword. But it doesn't seems to do anything to the monsters I hit, beside normal sword damages.

For the staff, there are no passive effects listed, and the active effect is called "Murmur of Alrond", and when I activate it, I'm surrounded by a dark aura menacing with spikes of darkness. Once again, there is no obvious effect of what this aura do.

So, my question is, does this sword and staff do anything special, or are they just for showing off?

Comment: I give them a rating of *at least* 3 epic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The staff info *is* hidden away on magickapedia, just need to dig a bit. :P

> The Epic Staff allows you to buff yourself with Whispers of Alrond, whereupon a countdown bar similar to that of the Shield spell will tick down underneath your health bar, and a black chaos star appears underneath your wizards feet. The buff lasts longer than it takes for the staff to recharge, making it possible to keep the buff up indefinitely. While Whispers of Alrond persists everything you do becomes roughly 11% more powerful, this goes for weapon damage and heals as well as spells and shields or barriers.

Found [here](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Epic_Staff), linked from [here.](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Wizard_Model)

Comment: Great, now, to find what this damn sword does

Comment: Because, of course, the staff goes up to 11.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing Magicka it's likely just a reference to something funny.  It is probably just some cool effects placed on normal items.

[Here](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Items)  is a reference list of items

Comment: Well, the Epic items are not in this list, so it don't really help me...

Comment: I assume [Epic](http://www.wowpedia.org/Epic) is a World of Warcraft reference.

Comment: @Powerlord was WoW really the first to call them 'Epics'?

Comment: I remember playing EQ 1 and seeing epics each class had an epic weapon class. Wow just made the term popular with more people.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Likely not, but WoW has like 14 times the subscribers as EQ1 has ever had.